# OpenGL color not working using lighting

Tags: c, opengl

I have a chess boards.
Doing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        drawSquare(i, j);
        int type = board[i][j];
        if (type != 0)
            drawPiece(i, j, type);
    }
```

Paints 64 squares, using this code:

```
int color = (x + z) % 2;
glColor3b(color, color, color); // also tried 3f

glPushMatrix(); {
    glTranslatef(x, 0, z);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); {
        glVertex3f(0, 0.01, 0);
        glVertex3f(0, 0.01, 1);
        glVertex3f(1, 0.01, 1);
        glVertex3f(1, 0.01, 0);
    } glEnd();
} glPopMatrix();
```

And indeed, there is a big square shown on the screen, of size 8x8. However, the image is showing that all squares are in the same color, which they should not be, as I printed `color`, and it does alternate 0/1.

Here is how it looks: (because of not-that-great AA, you can see each edge square's border and validate that there are 8)

[image]

The lighting I am using is:

```
static float g_lightPos[4] = { 10, 10, 100, 1 };
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, g_lightPos);
```

Comment: Which lighting? There is non in your code.

Comment: @BDL added the lighting code

Comment: I see no material definition, I see no light color definition, I see no normals. How do you expect to get what you're looking for here? Also, it's 2017 ... PLEASE learn modern OpenGL. You're using paradigms from the last century.

Comment: @thokra thanks for pointing me in a direction, I'll read about it. I know it's 2017, but academia does not

Comment: @Amit You should tell them glLight* was the part of the first release of OpenGL 1992! and deprecated by version 3.1 2009! Thats basically a history course.

Comment: @Amit: If your edu institution does still not teach modern OpenGL, you can still learn it for yourself. There is absolutely no benefit to learning legacy OpenGL first. What university/college are you attending?

Comment: @eldo I normally send them an alternative up to date syllabus for a course, if I see it is old. I will do for this one as well, but I am unable to code differently, because of the version they use for exercise checking.

Comment: @thokra see comment above. This one - http://www.ash-college.ac.il/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL using lighting requires a material to be set, and does not rely on the current color.

Replace:

```
glColor3b(color, color, color);
```

With: (For example)

```
GLfloat c[] = { color, color, color, 1 };
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, c);
```

Many thanks to commenters of the post above who pointed me in the right direction.